# Consolidating and editing Azure Tags in bulk with no data loss or outage?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

How can I rectify the below Azure Tags that is miss-spelled or has some blank space or typo error?

Is there any script that can Edit and replace all the tag into the correct keyword https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-aztag?view=azps-4.8.0

from:

```
  Name        Count
  Cost-Center    750
  Cost-Centre    250
  Cost Center    250
  Cost Centre    500
```

into:

```
   Name            Count
   Cost Center     1750
```

Preferably in bulk so no need to manually inspect all objects and replacing it manually one by one.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very tricky and you must make double sure what typos you want to look for in order to change the Name into a valid one.

Something like this perhaps

```
# testdata
$azTags = @"
Name,Count
Cost-Center,750
Cost-Centre,250
Cost Center,250
Cost Centre,500
Department,5
Dept,15
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# find misspelled names using wildcards and replace with hardcoded correct name
$azTags | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'Cost*Cent*' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name = 'CostCenter' }
$azTags | Where-Object { $_.Name -like 'Dep*' } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name = 'Department' }

# group the objects and calculate the sum of all Count properties
$azTags | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Count = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Output

```
Name       Count
----       -----
CostCenter  1750
Department    20
```

---

A maybe better way is to build a hashtable with keys containing the correct spelling and as value a regex string that tries to match all the bad spellings you encounter. (using `-like` with wildcards as above is probably too crude)

Of course, you will have to first get a list of all the bad names and from that figure out what the regex should be to catch them all..

As example, you could have this:

```
Name                Count
----                -----
Cost-Center           750
   Cost-Centre        250  
Cost Center           250
Cost   Centre         500
Department              5
 Dept                  15
Dpt.                    1
IT                      3
  I.T.                  6
Information Technology  4
```

Then below might clean up all the `yang` and replace it with `yin`

```
# testdata
$azTags = @"
Name,Count
Cost-Center,750
   Cost-Centre,250  
Cost Center,250
Cost   Centre,500
Department,5
 Dept,15
Dpt.,1
IT,3
  I.T,6
Information Technology,4
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv

# create a hashtable of correct names (yin) and a regex string containing bad matches (yang)
$hash = @{
    'CostCenter' = '^\s*Cost[^C]+Cent[re]\s*'
    'Department' = '^\s*(Dep[^a]+|Dpt\.?)\s*'
    'IT'         = '^\s*(I\.?T\.?|Information[^T]+)\s*'
}

# loop through the keys and replace the items in $azTags that match the yang
foreach ($yin in $hash.Keys) {
    $azTags | Where-Object { $_.Name -match $hash[$yin] } | ForEach-Object { $_.Name = $yin }
}
```

When that is done, you're able to group the items by name and get the total of the `Count` values:

```
# group the objects and calculate the sum of all Count properties
$azTags | Group-Object Name | ForEach-Object {
    [PsCustomObject]@{
        Name = $_.Name
        Count = ($_.Group | Measure-Object -Property Count -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Name       Count
----       -----
CostCenter  1750
Department    21
IT            13
```

Comment: what if the yang contains Blank Space in front or at the back of the keyword ?

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I have added new code. Hopefully that suits your needs better

Comment: thank you for your support, so I assume in this case I can just use:
Update-AzTag -ResourceId /subscriptions/{subId} -Tag $azTags -Operation Merge
As per your script above and this command: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/update-aztag?view=azps-4.8.0

Comment: @SeniorSystemsEngineer I guess so, but I can't test that.. Be very careful an try it put on a testset to make sure you don't ruin anything important...